# different XML types

Tags: xml, xslt, dom, sax, dtd

I need just simple definitions of these XML types:

```
DOM, SAX, XPath, XSL, XSLT, XML Schema, DTD
```

where these above xml are used?

I will appreciate any help

Comment: Those are not, for the most part, "types of XML". And Wikipedia will tell you where they are used.

Comment: @Phillipa, Its a sort of too basic question .. questions of these type are not encouraged in SO. Start working on them, try some examples, if you face any issue then come to SO seeking help :)

Comment: For now .. refer http://www.w3schools.com/ it covers pretty much everything that you have mentioned in your Q ..

Comment: @Quentin how many minus votes you want to see for this question, i think -3 is not at all enough

Comment: @infantprogrammer'Aravind' yes i am reading from that site and why you have written infant pro....I think earning 2000+ reputation is no more infant rather should be matured programmer. So your name should be "Matured Programmer'Arvind'"

Comment: Don't go near W3Schools, it is [awful](http://w3fools.com/)

Comment: @Phillipa — Depends on how many people think your question "does not show any research effort" (to quote the tooltip on the vote down button).

Comment: @Quentin, not precisely .. its good to practice basics (with try-it windows).. Its known that w3schools isn't perfect but not awful com'on .. :)

Comment: @Phillipa, World is too vast to call ourselves 'masters' .. bro :)

Comment: @infantprogrammer'Aravind' — No, it is awful. It has many errors, avoids best practise wherever possible, and if there is an opportunity to create a security hole in example code, it will (and not mention the problem).

Comment: @Quentin, Agreed ! They teach table layout for site-designing :D I think http://zvon.org/comp/m/tutorial.html and http://www.tizag.com/ should be fine :)

Comment: @infantprogrammer'Aravind'  yeah!! agreed!!

Answer (score -1):

XML Namespaces enable the same document to contain XML elements and attributes taken from different vocabularies, without any naming collisions occurring. Although XML Namespaces are not part of the XML specification itself, virtually all XML software also supports XML Namespaces.

XML Base defines the xml:base attribute, which may be used to set the base for resolution of relative URI references within the scope of a single XML element.
The XML Information Set or XML infoset describes an abstract data model for XML documents in terms of information items. The infoset is commonly used in the specifications of XML languages, for convenience in describing constraints on the XML constructs those languages allow.

xml:id Version 1.0 asserts that an attribute named xml:id functions as an "ID attribute" in the sense used in a DTD.

XPath defines a syntax named XPath expressions which identifies one or more of the internal components (elements, attributes, and so on) included in an XML document. XPath is widely used in other core-XML specifications and in programming libraries for accessing XML-encoded data.

XSLT is a language with an XML-based syntax that is used to transform XML documents into other XML documents, HTML, or other, unstructured formats such as plain text or RTF. XSLT is very tightly coupled with XPath, which it uses to address components of the input XML document, mainly elements and attributes.

XSL Formatting Objects, or XSL-FO, is a markup language for XML document formatting which is most often used to generate PDFs.

XQuery is an XML-oriented query language strongly rooted in XPath and XML Schema. It provides methods to access, manipulate and return XML, and is mainly conceived as a query language for XML databases.

XML Signature defines syntax and processing rules for creating digital signatures on XML content.

XML Encryption defines syntax and processing rules for encrypting XML content.

Copied from http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/XML...

Comment: You have defined a bunch of terms the question doesn't ask about, and haven't defined a bunch that it does ask about.

Comment: @Quentin i just try to pass what ever info i got. Thanks for the minus vote. :)

Comment: @Quentin can you define that bunch which this question asks about

Comment: @Phillipa — I could, but "Go look them up on Wikipedia" is more succinct and leads to a more detailed answer.